# How to change database (e.g. "use my_database") using RJDBC in R-Studio?

Tags: r, rjdbc

I'm having trouble finding the correct command to change databases in R-Studio.  I know I can connect to a specific database at the initial connection but I can't seem to find the correct way to execute a "use" command (e.g. "use my_schema").

The following fail with various errors:

```
dbSendQuery(conn, "use my_schema");

dbExecute(conn, "use my_schema");

dbSendStatement(conn, "use my_schema");
```

I'm not finding what I'm looking for in the documentation here:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RJDBC/versions/0.2-8/topics/JDBCConnection-methods

https://www.progress.com/blogs/complete-guide-to-r-for-datadirect-odbc-jdbc

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Executing-use-commands-in-R-Studio

https://rdrr.io/cran/RJDBC/

Comment: Depending on the methods available to your specific driver class, you can use `conn@jc$setSchema("my_schema")`.